# Material-UI v4 DataGrid toolBar prop not accepting csvOptions

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am trying to add some custom csvOptions to a mat-ui v4 DataGrid, but it is not accepting those options.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { useDemoData } from "@mui/x-data-grid-generator";

export default function ExportSelectorGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: "Commodity",
    rowLength: 4,
    maxColumns: 6
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        {...data}
        components={{
          Toolbar: GridToolbar
        }}
        componentsProps={{
          toolbar: {
            csvOptions: { delimiter: ";" } // <---- here
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

/***
RESULT:
Desk,Commodity,Trader Name,Trader Email,Quantity
D-1600,Cocoa,Ronald Malone,gewcu@vinwuz.by,"7,238"
D-1965,Coffee C,Todd Hammond,ovlo@comeh.sb,"70,264"
D-2173,Coffee C,Alexander Salazar,bo@ufhehhaw.sj,"36,223"
D-4616,Rough Rice,Bruce Ferguson,ih@zorihanu.cy,"19,020"
**/
```

If I do it with a custom tool bar (see following code snippet), then it works.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  DataGrid,
  GridToolbar,
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridToolbarExport
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { useDemoData } from "@mui/x-data-grid-generator";

function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarExport csvOptions={{ delimiter: ";" }} />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}

export default function ExportSelectorGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: "Commodity",
    rowLength: 4,
    maxColumns: 6
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        {...data}
        components={{
          Toolbar: CustomToolbar
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


/** 
RESULT
Desk;Commodity;Trader Name;Trader Email;Quantity
D-1600;Cocoa;Ronald Malone;gewcu@vinwuz.by;7,238
D-1965;Coffee C;Todd Hammond;ovlo@comeh.sb;70,264
D-2173;Coffee C;Alexander Salazar;bo@ufhehhaw.sj;36,223
D-4616;Rough Rice;Bruce Ferguson;ih@zorihanu.cy;19,020
**/
```

My question is: why is the first code snippet not working and why is the second one working? And how can I solve the first code snippet?

Thank you :)